# How to get C# VSTO to build in .NET framework 4.5

Tags: c#, vsto, .net-4.5

All my projects in my solution are set to build with .net framework 4.5.

I'm trying to create a C# VSTO project however cannot assign the .net 4.5 target framework. This is required so I can reference other projects in my VSTO project.

The error states that the project cannot be used against the targeted framework (.net 4.5).

Alternatively, do I have to implement the excel add-in without using a VSTO project?

Comment: Wait until VS2012 RTM before you do this.

Comment: All my projects are built in .net 4.5 though! Is there no way of getting the VSTO project to reference these 4.5 projects? Alternatively I was going to create my own connection class which extends from Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2 instead of using the VSTO project - not sure if that will solve my issue though.

Comment: The following article offers some insight on the problem, and a proposed solution.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d8089c11-3ca8-453e-885f-757db2cd5152

Answer (score 2):

There is an updated VSTO 4 redistributable here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35594

Notice that in this release the version has been bumped from 10.0.31119.0 to 10.0.40302.0 and it also supports Office 2013.

This release also works for both the x86 and 64 office installs, eliminating the need to choose the correct installer which is nice.

**Update**
It seems the previous download page has been removed. You can try to get the installer from the direct link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/4/9/949B0B7C-6385-4664-8EA8-3F6038172322/vstor_redist.exe

**Update 2**
Microsoft has released VSTO 10.0.40303.0, a fix for 10.0.40302.0, on 12/21/2012 and it is available from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35594 again.

Comment: The Link is broken.  Where can we find 40302? Thanks

Comment: You are right, it looks like that download page has been removed.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917, which use to point to the 40302 version now points to the previous version as x86 only.

To download the x86/64 combined installer for .40302 try this direct download link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/4/9/949B0B7C-6385-4664-8EA8-3F6038172322/vstor_redist.exe

Comment: The persistent link (as referenced by MSDN documentation is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=140384). If you're needing to just reference the EXE file itself, you can use the persistent links http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917 or http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158918 for the latest version.  See my full answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13503007.

Comment: The problem I find with these persistent links is that they are not persistent across version changes to VSTO. The go link has swapped between the x86 version, the 40302 version, back to the x86 version, and is now pointing to the 40303 version all within the last 2 months. This makes it very difficult to make a bootstrapping installer with WIX for both x86 and 64bit since the dependencies are different and the remote payload signature changes.

Comment: @Dan - Your Update 2 link is broken, but your first Update still works.

Comment: Though when it installs, it seems nothing changes. I am still unable to target .NET 4.5 with Office 2010, and Office 2013 projects do not show up in the "Add New Project" wizard. The same also happens when I try to install the version linked to by @MichaelZlatkovsky. I wish there could be some official response to this, because I'm not finding anything on Google.

Comment: Trysis, there is a difference between runtime vs. design-time compatibility for .NET 4.5+.  At the runtime level, any VSTO Runtime versions 10.0.40303 and up support .NET 4.5.

At design-time (e.g., in Visual Studio), it used to be that Office 2010 projects supported only .NET 4.0, and you would need an Office 2013 project in order to use .NET 4.5.

However, as of Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 Release Candidate that went out today (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/07/02/update-3-release-candidate-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx), Office 2010 projects now does support .NET 4.5 & up.